# Not getting any data from getStaticProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a next.js project and I'm trying to get the list of gyms from getStaticProps like this:

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import { useState } from "react";
import { server } from '../config';

export default function Map ({gyms}){
  console.log("data = "+ JSON.stringify(gyms));

  return (
    <MapContainer>
      <TileLayer url={`I deleted the url`} attribution='Nothing to see here' />

      {gyms.map((gym, index) => {
        return (
          <Marker
            key={index}
            position={[gym.address1, gym.address2]}
            draggable={true}
            animate={true}
          > 
          </Marker>
        );
      })}
    </MapContainer>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/gyms`)
  const response = await res.json()
  const gyms = response.gyms 
  console.log("gyms list = "+ gyms);
  if (!gyms) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }
  return {
    props: {
      gyms,
      // Will be passed to the page component as props
    },
  };
  
}
```

As you can see I have one console.log in the getStaticProps, that returns nothing, and another console log in the component that returns "data = undefined"

The error that I get is: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: the getStaticProps not returning nothing means you have problem in your API

Comment: I used the exact same code in another component, and It gets the list of the gyms correctly

Comment: If the endpoint is working then there's something wrong with the request you make in `getStaticProps`. Is the URL correct? Is the API you're making the request against external or an API route?

Comment: the server variable is correct nad this URL: `${server}/api/gyms` is the API URL for the list of gyms. when I visit it manually I get the list of gyms in a json format.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is from the 'gyms' prop. Please make sure if you are using useEffect in the component where you are using Map, the array variable should be in the array. Since you are getting the array as undefined then this is the most possible problem. Just put it in the array like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
       //Code goes here...
}, [gyms])
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work: 
const [gymList, setGymList] =useState(gyms);
  useEffect(() => {
    setGymList(gyms);
  }, [gyms]);